# Download document from server using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, download

I have an AngularJS application which needs to download documents from a secure (third party) server. The application is a simple document viewer, displaying document details and allowing the download of that document.

When the user clicks download, a request is sent to the server containing the ID of the document (along with user credentials) and part of the response is a string, containing the details for the document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DocDownload xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://some_url.co.uk/">
  <success>true</success>
  <errorText />
  <status>dsOK</status>
  <documentID>46386</documentID>
  <documentSize>15246</documentSize>
  <document>JVBERi0xLjQNJcjIyMjIyMgNMSAwIG9iago8PC9O[…]</document>
</DocDownload>
```

As you can see, the `<document>` tag contains the information I require.

**The request**

```
function download(userID, accessKey, siteID, cid, documentTitle){
    $http.get(serviceUrl + "docDownload?" + queryFromJson({
        accessKey: accessKey, 
        userID: userID,
        siteID: siteID,
        documentID: cid
    })).then(
        function successCallback(response){
            var documentString= getDocumentStringFromResponse(response);
            //storeDocumentWithTitle(documentTitle, documentString)
        }, function errorCallback(response){
            //do something
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: The "download" tag may not be as useful as the tag for the specific angularjs version you're using (as it's most likely 1.2.x since you're supporting IE8).

Comment: I am on AngularJS v1.4.8

Comment: To be honest, browser compatibility isn't strictly necessary - this is experimental work rather than production so just assume we are working for IE11 for now. If things need changing for compatibility I will revisit it at a later date.

Comment: Ah, yes, Angular dropped IE8 support in 1.3.x I think. Anyways, then you should probably get rid of the IE8 and IE9 tags, as well as the corresponding requirement from your question, because I'd hazard a guess the answers will be quite different depending on whether those browsers need to be supported or not.

Comment: Done it thanks @Jeroen